# Set cookie when the website opened first time in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I'm writing localization with cookies. Localization works fine with cookies, but I want to set default language for someone who opened the website first time. So, I created a middleware for that and registered in route middlewares:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    get_cookie('lang') ?? set_cookie('lang', 'az');

    return $next($request);
}
```

`get_cookie` and `set_cookie` comes from custom helpers:

```
if (!function_exists('get_cookie')) {
    function get_cookie($name)
    {
        return Cookie::get($name);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('set_cookie')) {
    function set_cookie($name, $value)
    {
        return Cookie::queue($name, $value, time() * 360 * 60);
    }
}
```

The issue is when I first opened website it sets cookie, but it isn't shows website with cookie. But, second time I opened website it shows the website with cookie.
I googled it and found this in stack overflow:

```
if($request->hasCookie('lang')) {
    return $next($request);    
}

$response = $next($request);
return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('lang', 'az'));
```

But it didn't work out for me, I think it works for old versions of laravel. I'm assuming that, I'm using middleware in the wrong way, but I didn't figured out. Any advice will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I changed middleware's place $routeMiddleware to $middlewareGroups. I think AddQueuedCookiesToResponse middleware has to be in that middleware list. But, it doesn't seem to be help. Maybe, there has to be another middleware in the list?

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SetLanguage::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: You'll have to make sure that this middleware runs before the middleware that uses the lang cookie

Comment: I changed middleware's place $routeMiddleware to $middleware and even placed into first element of array. But, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't managed to find a way out to get it work with cookies. So, I just simply used sessions instead of cookies. So, in the middleware I set lang variable to session.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!$request->session()->get('lang')) {
        session(['lang' => 'az']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```